# Concatenate related contact names in a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, relationships, loop, childrecords

I have a junction called MeetingContactRelation to link attendees to a meeting:

Meeting - MeetingContactRelation - Contact

I have a hidden rich text field on Meeting and want to store the concatenated list of Contacts' names in it, so I can merge it into a Lightning template.

The idea is when Meeting is saved, Process Builder calls a flow which iterates over all the MeetingContactRelations. For each relation it will look up the name of the related contact and Add it via a concatenation formula to the merge field.

I get this error.

The flow failed to access the value for MeetingContactRelation.Contact__r.Name because it hasn’t been set or assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a get records element in there to get all the meetingContactRelation records.  In the get records element you need to specify that you want to store contact__c in the resulting record collection.  You can only reference fields that you query

Comment: I didn't quite understand at first but now resolved it thank you. You have to specify that those fields are picked up when doing the quick find.